# PayPal MySQL Subscription integration

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to integrate PayPal Subscription into my site... but am having some trouble (my coding knowledge is limited, and Paypal's instructions are very complicated for new programmers).

I have a form (that I pulled from the tutorial https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-subscriptions-payment-gateway-integration-php/). It pulls some variables from a javascript select form, and others from set constant variables.

```
<form action="<?php echo PAYPAL_URL; ?>" method="post">
    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_ID; ?>">
    <!-- Specify a subscriptions button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <!-- Specify details about the subscription that buyers will purchase -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="<?php echo $item_name; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" id="item_number" value="<?php echo $item_number; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo CURRENCY; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="item_price" value="<?php echo $item_price; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" id="interval_count" value="<?php echo $interval_count; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" id="interval" value="<?php echo $interval; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="srt" value="52">
    <!-- Custom variable user ID -->
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $loggedInUserID; ?>">
    <!-- Specify urls -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_RETURN_URL; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL; ?>">
    <!-- Display the payment button -->
    <input class="buy-btn" type="submit" value="Buy Subscription">
</form>
```

My question ... the tutorial shows how to submit a GENERIC subscription (you set the price, length and interval for the subscription within the hidden fields) ... I was wondering what variables I need to send to PayPal to submit a subscription that is declared on paypals site (using the PayPal Plan Id). Is there is a hidden field that I can add for the plan id, and what is the "name" for that field? If I add the plan id, do I still need the price, interval and length (since the plan is already declared in PayPal)?

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Subscription integrations using a form post (or equivalent parameter) redirection to PayPal are deprecated and should certainly not be used on any new site. Disregard that ancient tutorial and follow PayPal's current subscription integration documentation, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/ . For notifications, instead of IPN register a listener URL for the webhook event PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED (it is the only important event)